# How to make two Threads wait and notify the correct way in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: java, multithreading

I followed some discussion on the website and implemented some suggestions but I was not able to complete the task.

I have this assignment to build Tic Tac Toe game in Java.

There's a lot of tutorials on the web I know, but I wanted to build it using threads for each player so that only one player at a time could enter X/O to the board and I was not able to figure out the implementation for the wait/ notify.

To be honest, I find it a bit confusing! I guess the logic is 90% done, and I am wondering how to finish it.

Basically, I have these classes:

```
abstract public class Player extends Thread 

public class HumanPlayer extends Player 
public class MachinePlayer  extends  Player 
public class Board 
public class Game  
public class Main
```

I'll paste first the players classes. Notice the run method I tried to Synchronize on top of the gameOver variable:

Player.java

```
abstract public class Player extends Thread {

    abstract int getMyTurn() ;
    abstract String  getPlayerName() ;
    abstract void  setPlayerName(String n ) ;

    abstract  void setSign(int n ) ;

    abstract  int getSign() ;

}
```

MachinePlayer.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MachinePlayer  extends  Player {
    private String name ;
    private int sign ;
    Board board ;

    public MachinePlayer(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Player "+name+" turn:" );
        while (!board.isGameOver())
        {
            board.setCurrentPlayerTurn(this.getSign()); // i think it keeps track of which player is holding the lock ?
            Move move = generateRandomMove();
            board.makeMove(this, move.getX(), move.getY() );
        }

    }

    @Override
    int getMyTurn() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPlayerName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    void setSign(int sign) {
        this.sign  = sign ;
    }

    @Override
    int getSign() {
        return sign;
    }

    private Move generateRandomMove(){
        while (true)
        {
            int x = getRandomNumber(0,board.getBoardSize()) ;
            int y = getRandomNumber(0,board.getBoardSize()) ;
            if (board.isPositionAvalabile(x, y ))
            {
                return new Move(x,y);
            }
        }
    // todo implement the best move !
    }

    public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }

}
```

HumanPlayer.java

```
public class HumanPlayer extends Player {
    private String name ;
    private int  sign ;
    private Board board ;

    public HumanPlayer(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!board.isGameOver())
        {
            board.setCurrentPlayerTurn(this.getSign()); // I think it keeps track of which player is holding the lock ?
            Move move = requestMoveFormHuman(); // request move for human player // will be changed in the GUI?
            board.makeMove(this, move.getX() , move.getY()); // check for move logic here  >
        }
    }


    @Override
    int getSign() {
        return sign;
    }

    @Override
    int getMyTurn() {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPlayerName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    void setSign(int n) {
        this.sign = n ;
    }

    // logic
    private Move requestMoveFormHuman(){
        int i=0 ;
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            Move move = requestMove() ;
            int x = move.getX();
            int y = move.getY();
            if (board.isPositionAvalabile(x,y))
            {
                return new Move(x,y);
            }
        }

    }

    private Move requestMove() {
        System.out.println("Player "+name+" turn:" );
        System.out.println("Enter Row  number: ");
        int x = ScanInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Coulmn  number ");
        int y =  ScanInt();
        return new Move(x ,y ) ;
    }

    private int ScanInt(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // This method reads the number provided using keyboard
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        // Closing Scanner after the use
        return  num;
    }



}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game() ;
        game.start();
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {
    private int  currentPlayerTurn = 0 ;


    public int getBoardSize() {
        return boardSize;
    }

    private int boardSize ;
    private int[][] board_values ;
    private boolean gameOver ;

    private HashMap<String , String>  result_history;

    public Board(int boardSize) {
        this.boardSize = boardSize;

        board_values = new int[boardSize][boardSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < boardSize; j++)
                board_values[i][j] = 0 ;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private String getSign(int n) {
        if (n==1)
            return "X" ;
        if (n==2)
            return "0" ;
        return " " ; // empty cell
    }

    public  void printBoard(){
        // todo change to ui components
        for (int i = 0  ; i < boardSize ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0  ; j < boardSize ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
                System.out.print(" " + getSign(board_values[i][j])+ " ");
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------" );
        }
    }


    /** is this the Synchronized one ?  */
    public  boolean makeMove(Player player , int x , int y ) {

            /*Update Board Value
            insert 1 in the 2d board at x,y for player 1
            insert 2 in the 2d board at x,y for player 2
            */
            int sign = player.getSign();

            updateBoard(x,y , sign ) ;

            /*print Board*/
            printBoard();

            /* check for winner */
             doWeHaveAwinner(x,y , sign);

        return  true ;
    }

    /*check the whole row (x)  for if  all signs are equals
    , checks the whole column (x) for if  all signs are equals
    check diagonal  if x=y */
    private boolean doWeHaveAwinner(int x, int y, int sign) {
        // TODO: 16/01/2022
        return false ;

    }

    private void updateBoard(int x, int y , int sign ) {
        board_values[x][y] = sign ;
    }


    public boolean isPositionAvalabile(int x , int y ){
        return !(x>this.boardSize ||  x < 0  || y>this.boardSize || y < 0) ;
    }

    private void checkMove() {
        // todo > ?
    }
    private void resetBoard(){
        // todo set al values to 0

    }
    private void updateResultHistory(){
        // TODO: 16/01/2022 update <Winner Name , Ps+1 >
    }


    private int ScanInt(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any number: ");

        // This method reads the number provided using keyboard
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        // Closing Scanner after the use
        return  num;
    }

    /*Get Set*/
    public synchronized boolean isGameOver() {
        return gameOver;
    }

    public void setGameOver(boolean gameOver) {
        this.gameOver = gameOver;
    }

    public int getCurrentPlayerTurn() {
        return currentPlayerTurn;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayerTurn(int currentPlayerTurn) {
        this.currentPlayerTurn = currentPlayerTurn;
    }
}
```

And here is Game.java, it basically inits 2 players.

Notice that in each player init I passed the board instance as a parameter.

It might a look little bit messy but I think passing the board instance for the players is the important thing here. Also I called the player1().start and player2.start()

Game.java

```
public class Game  {
    private Player player1 ;
    private Player player2 ;
    private Board board ;

    private void initBoard(){
        /* request board size */
        int board_size = requestBoardSize();
        board = new Board(board_size); // Synchronized class fields ?
    }

    private  void initGameMode(){
        /*
        init the players  objects as follows
        1 - for human-machine game
        2 - for machine-human game, and
        3 - for human-human game
        */

        System.out.println(Utils.str_gameType);
        Scanner scanner  = new Scanner( System.in);
        int game_mode = scanner.nextInt( );

        switch (game_mode) {
            case 1:
                /* init game type1  human-machine Game*/
                player1 = new HumanPlayer(board);
                player2 = new MachinePlayer(board);

                break;
            case 2:
                player1 = new MachinePlayer(board);
                player2 = new HumanPlayer(board);
                break;
            case 3:
                player1 = new HumanPlayer(board);
                player2 = new HumanPlayer(board);
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + game_mode);

        }

        player1.setSign(1);
        player2.setSign(2);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private void initPlayersName(){
        /*request name player 1  */
        System.out.println(Utils.str_player1Name); /*Scan first name*/
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name1 = scan1.next();
        player1.setPlayerName(name1);


        /*request name player 2  */
        System.out.println(Utils.str_player2Name); /*Scan first name*/
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name2 = scan2.next();
        player2.setPlayerName(name2);



    }

    public Game() {
        System.out.println(Utils.str_start_game);
        initBoard();
        initGameMode();
        initPlayersName();
    }

    public void start() {
        // todo change who starts first
        player1.start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    player2.start();
                }catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }).start();


    }

    private int requestBoardSize() {
        System.out.println(Utils.str_request_board_size);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        int i =  scanner.nextInt() ;
        return i ;

    }
    
}///End of Class
```

Comment: Are you required to use threads for this, e.g. for an academic assignment? I personally would not use them - since it is a console app, the computer can just keep track of whether it is the computer or the human's turn, and let the computer make a move after every human move (assuming all human moves require new console input).

Comment: yeah, it's for an academic assignment ! I agree, but we used threads so we can practice for practice ! also in part 2 of the assignment I'll Build GUI and implement sockets ! so if so , I think using threads is ok, do you agree ? also, i figured that the threads should be synchronized based on the curentPLayerTurn variable somehow, unfortiaintly didn't implement that yet @halfer

Comment: I disagree, I would not use threads for this. I am not an expert, but I don't think you can use threads anyway, if you are looking to gather user input. Thread isolation is meant to happen over microseconds, not over a number of seconds. I would advise talking to your course supervisor before going any further.